# Only use form action url if jquery function is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have been searching for hours and trying other code samples find on here and other places but nothing seems to work.

I only want my form to go to the action url if the email field is neither empty or invalid. If not i want nothing to happen except show my error message. This is my current script i am using but when my unsubscribe button is clicked it seems to go to the action url no matter what.

```
function isEmail(email) {
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9] . 
{2,4})+$/;
return regex.test(email);
}






function validateForm() {
if( !isEmail( document.getElementById('email_address').value ) ) { 
  var err = document.getElementById('error');
   err.show();
  $( "#submit" ).click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
    return false;
 } else { 
    return true;
 }    
 }
```

and the html looks like this

```
    <p id="error">Please enter your email address</p>

<form id="myForm" method="post" 
action="https://fe3e15707564057a7d1470.pub.s10.sfmc- 
content.com/tfuryofct5y? 
optc=%%=v(@optc)=%%&brand=%%=v(@brand)=%%&ceid=%%=v(@ceid)=%%" 
  onsubmit="return validateForm();">

<input type="text" placeholder="email address" name="email_address" 
id="email_address" align="center"/>

<p style="text-align:center;overflow:hidden;float:right;padding- 
right:8em;">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Unsubscribe" ></p>
 </form>
```

Jquery is not my strong suit so they may be way off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing javascript and jquery and causing the onclick to submit the form.

```
function validateForm() {
   var err = $('#error');
   if( !isEmail( document.getElementById('email_address').value ) ) {       
      err.show();
      return false;
   } else {
      err.hide();
      return true;
   }
}
```